# How to select a RAW column in an Eloquent Model?

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to add a custom column in my Eloquent model such as:

```
class Shape extends Eloquent
{
    public function getAreaAttribute()
    {
        return $this->width * $this->height;
    }
}
```

Which allows to build a query such as this:

```
Shape::where('area', '>', 42)->get();
```

What I could do is:

```
Shape::select(['*', DB::RAW('width * height AS area')])->where('area', '>', 42)->get();
```

But this is not in my model. Is it possible to get something like:

```
class Shape extends Eloquent
{
    public function getAreaColumn()
    {
        return DB::RAW('width * height AS area')
    }
}
```

Comment: What about adding a dynamic column to the mysql table which auto calculates the height * width? Then you can query it and add it to your model.

Comment: @TahaPaksu, I don't know about dynamic columns. Should you create a `VIEW` for this?

Comment: I added an answer about how to do this.

Comment: Just FYI, the query: `Shape::select(['*', DB::RAW('width * height AS area')])->where('area', '>', 42)->get();` won't work. You can't use `where()` on alias columns. You should use `having()` instead.

Comment: @Mozammil, you're right. I should have used `having` there

Comment: @TahaPaksu. I realized I was too far from my real usecase so I have asked another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54556064/how-to-create-a-complexe-virtual-column-in-an-eloquent-model)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define this in your migration:

```
$table->integer('area')->virtualAs('height * width');
```

to be generated on every read, or

```
$table->integer('area')->storedAs('height * width');
```

if you want to store the column in the database if you don't want the generation to be always.

and then add the `area` column to your model. This way you can use the field in both queries and models.

Comment: I upvote your answer because It does answers my question, but not my XY problem where the real raw column would be related to a joined table. Unfortunately it seems I cannot do `select` on virtual columns.

Comment: But you can on stored columns.

Comment: And where did you read that virtual columns can't be queried?

Comment: I tried this `CHANGE COLUMN area area INT(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE height + width = baz limit 1) STORED ;` but I get an `ERROR 1064`

Comment: you shouldn't use a subquery in AS () clause.

Answer (score -2):

I hope this code will help you

```
$result = DB::table('shape')
                 ->select(DB::raw('width * height AS area'))
                 ->where('area', '>', 42)
                 ->get();
```