# How to create a complexe virtual column in an Eloquent Model?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54555093/how-to-select-a-raw-column-in-an-eloquent-model), but I simplified too much my real problem. So I have created a separated question:

I have two tables. One holding intervals in days associated to a name such as `bimonthly = 15` and one other listing periodic actions and associated to an interval.

I would like to list the next periodic actions which is easy in pure SQL:

```
SELECT *, DATE_ADD(updated_at, INTERVAL days DAY) AS next_action 
FROM periodic_actions 
INNER JOIN intervals ON interval_id = intervals.id
HAVING next_action > NOW()
```

Here my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `intervals` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `days` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `periodic_actions` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `interval_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

And the content of intervals:

```
+----+----------+------+
| id | name     | days |
+----+----------+------+
|  1 | daily    |    1 |
|  2 | monthly  |   30 |
|  3 | annually |  365 |
+----+----------+------+
```

I would like to build the same query with Eloquent where I can use `where` on my virtual column `next_action`:

```
Action::orderBy('next_action', 'asc')
    ->where('next_action', '>', Carbon::now())
    ->get()
```

The closest I have, which I cannot hide into my Model is:

```
Action::join('intervals', 'interval_id', '=', 'intervals.id')
    ->select(['*', DB::RAW('DATE_ADD(updated_at, INTERVAL days DAY) AS next_action')])
    ->havingRaw(DB::RAW('next_action > NOW()'))->get();
```

Of course I have this base Model:

```
class Action extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'periodic_actions';

    public function interval() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Interval::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: If there's two tables involved, creating a view model might be a better solution. Check: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-view-models

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1:  Using a global scope to add the field to your select statements**

The one issue with virtual columns is Eloquent will try to update them if you don't prevent it.  You can exclude it from the $fillable array and use a [global scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#global-scopes) in your model to add the virtual column, something like:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::addGlobalScope('next_action', function (Builder $builder) {
        $builder->addSelect(DB::raw('DATE_ADD(updated_at, INTERVAL days DAY) AS next_action'));
    });
}
```

You'll have to keep in mind that this will couple your Model to MySQL since the date functions you're using won't work in databases like sqlite.

**Solution 2:  Using a MySQL view**

Normally what I do when I have multiple calculated fields is create a MySQL view.  Create the view with all the calculated fields you want, then you can create a new Eloquent model for that view without having to worry about query scopes.

The one caveat is you of course can't use create/update/delete on this model, but if you're only using the model for display purposes, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Do you put this method on the model itself?

Comment: Yes, this is a static method in the model class.

Comment: OP wants to use `where()` on his query. This solution would still not make that possible though, right? OP would need to use `having()` instead?

Comment: I agree where would be much better because I can build generic filters from Kendo Grid. But the `boot` solution is not that bad

Comment: @Mozammil, you're right, you would have to use having with a calculated field.

Comment: @nowox The other alternative, and something I do quite a bit in complex apps, is create a mysql view and a read-only model.  Updated my answer.

Comment: I think the MySQL view is the best solution, then I can keep my Eloquent model simple without too much kludges.